# Apache Axis2 - Services page not showing on SSL port 8443

Tags: apache, ssl, apache-axis

I am facing some problems when trying to access the Available Services page through the 8443 port. localhost:8443/axis2/services/

When I try to enter that url, it shows that has a Internal server error.

The welcome page of axis 2 works fine. localhost:8443/axis2/

If I use the 8080 port on Available Services page, it works great. localhost:8080/axis2/services/

Any tips to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "some problems" is a bit vague; I doubt that anybody will be able to propose a solution based on that problem description.

Comment: Sorry, the "some problems" means not showing the page. I am edinting the request right now.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that an aditional configuration is needed.

Edit axis2.xml (located on home folder of axis2/WEB-INF/conf) changing:

transportReceiver name="http"

to:

transportReceiver name="https"

I hope this may help someone that is facing the same problem.